# How to create groups without case when?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have wquestion about how to create groups without case when.

I do have data like this:

```
 date1  date2   random num,ber  rank within group 
  01.01.2016    01.01.2016  0.6818  1
  01.01.2016    01.01.2016  0.5213  2
  01.01.2016    01.01.2016  0.5017  3
01.01.2016  01.01.2016  0.4305  4
01.01.2016  01.01.2016  0.4087  5
01.01.2016  01.01.2016  0.3646  6
31.1.2016   31.1.2016   0.173   1
31.1.2016   31.1.2016   0.1577  2
31.1.2016   31.1.2016   0.1577  3
31.1.2016   31.1.2016   0.1462  4
31.1.2016   31.1.2016   0.1462  5
04.02.2016  04.02.2016  0.5279  1
04.02.2016  04.02.2016  0.4354  2
04.02.2016  04.02.2016  0.4098  3
04.02.2016  04.02.2016  0.387   4
04.02.2016  04.02.2016  0.3823  5
```

I want to create a new attibute named as NUMBER OF GROUP. 
I want to have

```
01.01.2016 = 1, 31.01.2016 as 2, 04.02.2016 as 3.
```

Do you know any trick how to do it without case when?

I have tried:

```
  rank () over (partition by a.date1  order by a.date2 ASC) as group_number
```

but I am getting only 1 in it.

Thank you for your help.
Bara

Comment: If there is some kind of logical function (i.e. every 3 weeks or something) then you can use maths... so let us in on how you are actually deciding this.

Comment: There is no such function. Dates are random.

Comment: you have two date columns, do you want to  number only the first one or only the second or  the unique combination of the both dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you want to get rank of any dates. You may use DENSE_RANK()

```
select date1, date2 ,random_number, DENSE_RANK() over (order by date1) as rnk
from your_table
```

Comment: This is great! I have tried it only with partition and it didnt work :) great!!! thank you, you saved me a LOT of time!